# How to get string on path in php?

Tags: php

I got a path variable in array.

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$a = parse_url($url);
print_r($a);
```

`$a's` output=>

```
 Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => localhost [path] => /counterSistemi/hero/earthshaker/ )
```

I just want to get earthshaker in this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
echo basename($a['path']);
```